# Get message inbound properties

Tags: mule

im having trouble getting message inbound properties, somehow its coming as null, here is the code:

```
<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        log.info "${message.getInboundProperty('user-agent')}"
        muleContext.client.dispatch('vm://log-request.in', message)
        message
     </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>

<pattern:web-service-proxy name="service" transformer-refs="noopLoggingTransformer" inboundAddress="${serverName}/services/Logradouros/LogradouroServico" outboundAddress="${targetServer}/servicos/v2/service.svc" wsdlFile="LogradouroServicos.wsdl">
</pattern:web-service-proxy>

<jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source name="WSA" user="${database.user}" password="${database.pass}" url="${database.url}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" doc:name="PostgreSQL Data Source">
</jdbc-ee:postgresql-data-source>

<jdbc-ee:connector name="jdbcConnector" dataSource-ref="WSA" validateConnections="false" transactionPerMessage="true" queryTimeout="10" pollingFrequency="10000" doc:name="JDBC"> 
    <jdbc-ee:query key="wsadb" value="insert into inbound_messages (payload, timestamp, agent, ip_from, endpoint, soap_operation) values ('', now(), #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('user-agent').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS').toString()], #[groovy: return message.getInboundProperty('http.request').toString()], '');"></jdbc-ee:query>  
</jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="log-request" doc:name="log-request"> 
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="log-request.in" />
    <logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['user-agent']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="wsadb" responseTimeout="10000" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="jdbcConnector" doc:name="Persist raw message" />
</flow>
```

What it prints out is "null" and i dont know how to make it print the property from message...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to use Groovy:

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['user-agent']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

But your bigger issue is that you are not propagating the inbound properties to the outbound scope prior to dispatching to `vm://log-request.in`.

You need to propagate the properties you want to carry forward:

```
<scripting:transformer name="noopLoggingTransformer">
    <scripting:script engine="groovy">
        def props = [:]
        props['User-Agent'] = message.getProperty('User-Agent', org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.INBOUND)
        muleContext.client.dispatch('vm://log-request.in', payload, props)
        message
     </scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Of course, you can iterate the inbound property names to copy them all.

Comment: yeah i just found out that they changed from () to [] + a few things more, thank you again David :)

Answer (score 1):

Property name is `User-Agent` and as David pointed out, `#message.inboundProperties['User-Agent']]` is the `MEL` way to get it.

Did you make sure `User-Agent` property is set on the `mule message` when you're trying to access it. It's not always there

Remember `inbound` properties are not propagated unless you copy property manually like by

`<copy-properties propertyName="*"/>`

Comment: If i log into the transformer it works out fine using MEL and all, but when i try accessing the property inside the flow it comes as null... but i can print #[message.payload] for example...

Comment: @JaderWallauer  Are you saying that this prints `#message.inboundProperties['User-Agent']]` fine?

Comment: No, what i said is if you print inside the transformer you will get the property but not in the flow, take a look in the code. In the flow you will only get null somehow...

Comment: Because inbound properties are not propagated to outbound scope